# What does a single audible signal every 30 seconds mean coming from the APC BackUPS BE550G-GR?

Tags: ups

I have APC Back UPS BE550G-GR installed at home. This is a home class device, and I bought it since I need only basic protection of my home network devices, and disk storage.

Recently device started producing ONE audible signal once every 30 seconds. This is very confusing since the manual only describes 4 (FOUR) signals every 30 seconds indicating on battery state. Device is receiving AC from wall outlet, and it is working like this for a week now.

UPS is about one year old and replace battery light is off. Everything looks perfectly normal, except for this audible alert from device.

I did not call APC support yet, but I will try that next work day. I tried connecting with APC PowerChute Personal Edition since I hoped that it is possible to silence the alarm, but although there is option to disable alarms it did not produce any effect. Device keeps *beeping* every 30 seconds. What I also tried is disconnecting from AC and reconnecting, and turning device off and back on, but it did not help.

Does anybody has idea what could cause this, and what to do?

Comment: Have you tried calling APC's support line? What was their answer? What other steps have you taken to try to find the answer yourself? (This information is helpful because it avoids duplication of effort, as well as that it shows evidence of [prior research](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) on your part.)

Comment: So, what I tried now is to disconnect everything (equipment), took out the battery and disconnected it from UPS (two cables attached to battery). When I returned everything back and powered on, the sound is not produced anymore. UPS is on for 10 minutes now. I will post comment if it starts again.

Comment: @Marko any news on this? My UPS has starting to do the same, despite everything being OK with both the input voltage and battery status etc. I have also tried disabling the beeping using UPSCMD and while it reports back as disabled, it's still beeping. Status lights indicate normal operation.

Answer (score 1):

An occasional single beep as described may just be an indicator it is operating normally and functional in protecting the load. If you start to receive one beep every 5 seconds, your UPS may be in what's called Low Voltage Sleep Mode; whereupon it is attempting to charge itself following a shutdown.

You can see a shortlist of beep codes here:

http://www.apc.com/solutions/display.cfm?id=78760AB5-5056-AE36-FE73D366CF632A0A&ISOCountryCode=in

You should also be able to find a full list of beep codes in the instruction manual of your device.